# multiple density plot with slope line added in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, radix, density-plot

I want to creat density plot with multiple groups and add slope line for the means. The plot looks like following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
data1 <- data.frame(x1 = c(rep(1,50), rep(2,50), rep(3,50), rep(4,50), rep(5,50)),
                    y1 = c(rnorm(50,10,1), rnorm(50,15,2), rnorm(50,20,3), rnorm(50,25,3), rnorm(50,30,4)))
data1$x1 <- as.factor(data1$x1)
ggplot(data1, aes(x = y1, y = x1, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - stat(ecdf)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Tail probability", direction = -1)
```

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to construct the red line.  You can either (1) use geom_line through points representing the group means, or (2) fit a regression through the data.

(1) will be truncated to fit the data, (2) can be extended beyond the data, but will only look right if there is an overall linear relationship between your x and y.

Code for (1)

```
means <- aggregate(y1 ~ x1, data=data1, FUN=mean)

ggplot(data1, aes(x = y1, y = x1, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - stat(ecdf)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Tail probability", direction = -1) +
  geom_line(aes(x=y1, y=as.numeric(x1), fill=1), data=means, colour="red")
  // NB: need to override the fill aesthetic or you get an error
```

Code for (2)

```
regressionLine <- coef(lm(as.numeric(x1) ~ y1 , data=data1))
ggplot(data1, aes(x = y1, y = x1, fill = 0.5 - abs(0.5 - stat(ecdf)))) +
  stat_density_ridges(geom = "density_ridges_gradient", calc_ecdf = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Tail probability", direction = -1) +
  geom_abline(intercept=regressionLine[1], slope=regressionLine[2], colour="red")
```